# Help proving the following relation $(\eta^{\mu\nu}+u^\mu u^\nu)A_{\mu\nu}=0.$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, metric-tensor

I have to prove the following statement: let $A_{\mu\nu}$ be some antisymmetric tensor; prove that for a timelike unit vector ($u_\mu u^\mu=-1$) this relation holds: $$(\eta^{\mu\nu}+u^\mu u^\nu)A_{\mu\nu}=0.$$

I have written it out but I can find no identities in my notes or books that could help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $S^{\mu\nu}$ is symmetric and $A_{\mu\nu}$ is anti-symmetric, their contraction vanishes: $$S^{\mu\nu}A_{\mu\nu}=(S^{\nu\mu})(-A_{\nu\mu})=-S^{\nu\mu}A_{\nu\mu}=-S^{\mu\nu}A_{\mu\nu}\tag{1}.$$

In the first equality we used symmetry of $S$ and anti-symmetry of $A$. On the last equality we just noticed that $\nu$ and $\mu$ are dummy indices so they can be relabelled at will. In that case we relabel $\mu\leftrightarrow \nu$.

Since $S^{\mu\nu}A_{\mu\nu}=-S^{\mu\nu}A_{\mu\nu}$ we must have $S^{\mu\nu}A_{\mu\nu}=0$. This directly applies to your question.